# Python file not opening requires in submitting assignment on Coursera

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to submit the programming assignment of Coursera course using the `.py` file but as soon as I click on this `.py` file a window opens ask for email id and password and then after on enter click the window gets closed and it is not submitted.

Comment: See the discussion forum of that course

Comment: if discussion forum works then i will not ask this question here.

Comment: Try open as and then open it in a text editor

Comment: It is possible that your email provider does not want to send *.py files as attachments. I have worked at places that the firewall would strip them off as executables. We got around this by renaming the file with .txt at the end instead of .py.

Comment: can someone help in submitting the assignment, everything is completed in program it just need to be submitted i will provide the details for submission.